# Record voice and play in unity?

Tags: unity

i wanted to ask that does unity3d support audio record and playback option and if it does, how is it possible to just speak and the application will record the sound and play it back after a little interval say 2 seconds???

Comment: Please take a bit of time to research your question before posting - it will help you narrow down to the specific issues you need help with. In this case, [a 5-second search for "Unity microphone" gets the lead you need](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html). Read through that and, if you find you need further help, consider editing your question to specify where you're stuck.

Comment: @DMGregory please give me snippet example of this ,because I've new in unity.

Comment: This is not a code on demand service. If you're new and unsure how to proceed, the best way to start is to [search for Unity tutorials](https://www.google.ca/search?q=unity+tutorial) to build up your skills.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the class [`Microphone`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.html).

Here is a simple example copied verbatim from [the documentation of `Microphone.Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone.Start.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        AudioSource aud = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        aud.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 10, 44100);
        aud.Play();
    }
}
```

Note that this example requires an [Audio Source component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html) on the game object you have that script on. The settings of that audio source are used for playing back the recording.

I am also not sure if `"Built-in Microphone"` is guaranteed to exist on every system. When it doesn't work for you, try replacing it with `Microphone.devices[0]` to use the first available recording device. For a real game you likely want to have a setting in your options menu where the user can choose which device from the [`Microphone.devices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Microphone-devices.html) array they want to use.